# Why JavaScript throwing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: var is not defined' when var is defined

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript function

```
function B_modeWindow (id,cords) {  
    loading();

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            var cords = document.getElementById(cords)
            cords.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var xy = cords.split("x");          
            hideloading();
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","processMapEdit.php?id="+id+"&x="+xy[0]+"&y="+xy[1],true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

returns:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: xy is not defined
```

in:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","processMapEdit.php?id="+id+"&x="+xy[0]+"&y="+xy[1],true);
```

It seems that xy is just not there, but it's defined just 5 lines above! What is wrong here?

Comment: They're not defined in the same scope, so no, it actually isn't defined. But how are you hoping to open the request with the values it will get *after it's sent*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xy` is only defined in the scope of the anonymous function `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { // valid scope of xy }`. Thus, it's not accessible *outside* of this anonymous function. Use the following instead:

```
function B_modeWindow (id,cords) {  
    loading();

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var xy = cords.split("x"); 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var cordsElement = document.getElementById(cords);
            cordsElement.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;      
            hideloading();
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","processMapEdit.php?id="+id+"&x="+xy[0]+"&y="+xy[1],true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This way, the scope of `xy` is the function `B_modeWindow` instead of the anonynmous function.

Also, note that even ***if*** you could access `xy` outside of the anonymous function (which you can't), `xy` won't be defined as well, since you are defining it only when the AJAX request completes, and you need to use it to actually make the AJAX call.

Another suggestion is for you to use different variable names for `cords`. You are using it first to split its content by `x`, and then defining another `cords` variable to assign a DOM element. Although this works, it can be confusing.

Comment: Now it says `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'split' B_modeWindow.js:22
B_modeWindow B_modeWindow.js:22
(anonymous function)`

Comment: @user1656447: Please try my update. I got confused by the duplicated variable names called `cords`. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `xy` variable outside of `onreadystatechange` function for it to be available where you are using it.

This should work:

```
function B_modeWindow (id,cords) {  
    var xy = null; // defined xy here

    loading();

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            var cords = document.getElementById(cords)
            cords.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            xy = cords.split("x");          // removed var keyword here
            hideloading();
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","processMapEdit.php?id="+id+"&x="+xy[0]+"&y="+xy[1],true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Please note that ajax calls are asynic by default, so even if scope is fixed, the `xy` variable might not have what you are looking for. In that case, you will have to use callback inside ajax request somehow to capture the actual value

Comment: You say that `var xy = cords.split("x");` needs to be global, right?

Comment: Not necessarily global, it can be declared in `B_modeWindow`

Answer (score 0):

You put the declaration in the wrong function. Also, you'll want to give the `cords` in the callback a different name, or things will break.

```
function B_modeWindow (id,cords) {
    var xy = cords.split("x");

    loading();

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var cordsElement = document.getElementById(cords);
            cordsElement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            hideloading();
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "processMapEdit.php?id=" + id + "&x=" + xy[0] + "&y=" + xy[1], true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, xy is defined but it's defined within curly braces - it goes out of scope, or stops exiting by the time you get to the problem line. **EDIT: see below comments. This statement is of mine is just plain wrong **

To fix it, just define xy above the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()` line.
Or better yet, at the top of the func.

Comment: It's not about the curly braces, it's about the function; and the function hasn't even run at that time.

Comment: Er, yes it is about the curly braces - they just so happen in this case to designate the start and end of an anonymous function.  However you do make a good point about the block that they're in not having been run yet - somewhat irrelevant, but good nonetheless.

Comment: No, it's not about the curly braces. JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Try it: `var a = 5; {var a = 10;} console.log(a); // 10`

Comment: Thank-you minitech. :thumbsup:My most humble apologies are offered and are yours to accept or reject.